# Не открывается exe файл

Tags: python, pycharm, pygame, exe, pygame-menu

Написала игру на python в PyCharm, с использованием pygame и pygame_menu. Также используются jpg и txt файлы. С помощью pyinstaller сделала exe файл, но он не открывается. Уже задавала такой вопрос, посоветовали открыть exe через консоль и посмотреть выдаваемые ошибки, и вот, что выходит: >ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘pygame_menu’
Ошибка то вроде понятна, но как это исправить не понимаю, если перекидываю папку pygame_menu в dist рядом с exe, то ошибок становится еще больше(

Comment: Вот с этого места немного больше информации ```то ошибок становится еще больше```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "SnakeGame.py", line 5, in <module> 
  File "C:\final project\dist\SnakeGame\pygame_menu\__init__.py", line 33, in <module> 
    import pygame_menu.baseimage  # lgtm [py/import-and-import-from] 
  File "C:\final project\dist\SnakeGame\pygame_menu\baseimage.py", line 43, in <module> 
    from pygame_menu._base import Base 
  File "C:\final project\dist\SnakeGame\pygame_menu\_base.py", line 11, in <module> 
    from pygame_menu.utils import uuid4 
  Все не влезло дальше>> @ВладимирКлыков

Comment: File "C:\final project\dist\SnakeGame\pygame_menu\utils.py", line 46, in <module> 
    import uuid 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uuid' 
[14028] Failed to execute script 'SnakeGame' due to unhandled exception!

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос, и добавьте туда, ошибка будет в последних строках стектрейса... p.s. кажется вы поняли как читать ошибки, и теперь сможете найти все недостающие импорты, и так же положить их рядом :)